# Modifying output of google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.VERTICAL

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-translate

I've read this answer [Modifying element from google.translate.TranslateElement results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306015/modifying-element-from-google-translate-translateelement-results) as well as others dealing with modifying the style and loading of the Google Translate translate element.

The difference with my usage is that I'm using `layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.VERTICAL` instead of `SIMPLE`; all of the other answers deal with `SIMPLE`.

One issue I'm having is using `.fadeIn` on the `google-translate` div doesn't work. I still get a flash of text from `.goog-logo-link` and I see `Select a Language` before it changes to `Translate`.

That might have something to do with the `myTimer` function from [Modifying element from google.translate.TranslateElement results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306015/modifying-element-from-google-translate-translateelement-results) . But `myTimer` the only way I figured out how to change the text of `.goog-te-combo option:first` from `Select a Language` to `Translate`.

So,

1. Is there a more efficient way to change the text of `.goog-te-combo option:first` from `Select a Language` to `Translate`?
2. how can I get `.fadeIn` to work on the `google-translate` div so that changing the text from `Select a Language` to `Translate` and hiding `.goog-logo-link` is hidden until the entire div is faded in?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gfzcjwmv/7/

```
<script>
$(window).on('load', function() {
$(".goog-logo-link").empty();
$('.goog-te-gadget').html($('.goog-te-gadget').children());
$("#google-translate").fadeIn('1000');
});
</script>


<div id="google-translate">

<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
new google.translate.TranslateElement({
pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'af,ach,ak,am,ar,az,be,bem,bg,bh,bn,br',
layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.VERTICAL
}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

</div>


<script>

$(window).on('load', function() {

function cleartimer() {     
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        window.clearInterval(myVar); 
    }, 1000);             
}
function myTimer() {
    if ($('.goog-te-combo option:first').length) {
        $('.goog-te-combo option:first').html('Translate');
        cleartimer();
    }
}
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 300); 

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a more efficient way to change the text of .goog-te-combo
> option:first from Select a Language to Translate?

Looks like the timer is needed but it is enough if you wait for 0 milliseconds.

> how can I get .fadeIn to work on the google-translate div so that
> changing the text from Select a Language to Translate and hiding
> .goog-logo-link is hidden until the entire div is faded in?

To get the fadeIn to work you first need to set `display:none;` with css.

This is what it looks like
*(I have removed the line which removes the google link because that's violation of the terms of use)*

[image]

(Unfortunaltely the stacksnippet doesn't work) that's why [here is the working jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/b9tw8czn/1/)

```js
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
  pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'af,ach,ak,am,ar,az,be,bem,bg,bh,bn,br,bs,ca,chr,ckb,co,crs,cs,cy,da,de,ee,el,en,eo,es,es-419,et,eu,fa,fi, fo,fr,fy,ga,gaa,gd,gl,gn,gu,ha,haw,hi,hr,ht,hu,hy,ia, id,ig,is,it,iw,ja,jw,ka,kg,kk,km,kn,ko,kri,ku,ky,la, lg,ln,lo,loz,lt,lua,lv,mfe,mg,mi,mk,ml,mn,mo,mr,ms,mt, ne,nl,nn,no,nso,ny,nyn,oc,om,or,pa,pcm,pl,ps,pt-BR, pt-PT,qu,rm,rn,ro,ru,rw,sd,sh,si,sk,sl,sn,so,sq,sr, sr-ME,st,su,sv,sw,ta,te,tg,th,ti,tk,tl,tn,to,tr,tt, tum,tw,ug,uk,ur,uz,vi,wo,xh,yi,yo,zh-CN,zh-TW,zu',
  layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.VERTICAL
  }, 'google_translate_element');
}


$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.goog-te-gadget').html($('.goog-te-gadget').children());
  $("#google-translate").fadeIn('1000');


  function cleartimer() {     
      setTimeout(function(){ 
          window.clearInterval(myVar); 
      }, 500);             
  }
  function myTimer() {
      if ($('.goog-te-combo option:first').length) {
          $('.goog-te-combo option:first').html('Translate');
          cleartimer();
      }
  }
  var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 0); 

});
```

```css
#google-translate {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="google-translate">
  <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That works great. It appears that the sequence of the functions and combing them all into one script block made a big difference, too.

Comment: Ah, one detail I discovered that may or may not be fixable. When a language is selected, Google adds a toolbar at the top of the page with a "close'" button to return to the original page. When the toolbar is closed, goog-te-combo option:first reverts to "Select a Language." What would be great is to force a page reload when the toolbar is closed, or make myTimer fire again. Should I open a new question?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch long story short: https://jsfiddle.net/8m2xkez4/ short story long: if you set a language an observer will be instanciated which will give the possibility to check if `<html>` removes the class `translated`. if it removes that class we know the toolbar has been closed. so reset to "Translate"