# Reapplying CSS changes to the Google Translate widget after closing the translate bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, console.log, google-translate

I'm modifying the text and CSS of the Google Translate widget and have an error when using `addEventListener` and `querySelector` to reapply CSS and text changes after the Google Translate bar is closed and when the page is returned to the original language.

I'm suddenly getting an error `Uncaught TypeError: x.X is undefined` pointing to the line

`x.X.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', (event) => {`

This new error is probably due to a jQuery main library update.

How do I define `x.X`?

Thanks to caramba for the answer to my earlier question [Modifying output of google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.VERTICAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65941987/modifying-output-of-google-translate-translateelement-inlinelayout-vertical)  and for his followup in the Fiddle linked below.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8m2xkez4/

**Javascript:**

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (event) {
  if(false === document.documentElement.classList.contains('translated-ltr')) {
      renameGoogleSelectDropdown();
  }
});

var renameGoogleSelectDropdown = function(){
    function cleartimer() {     
      setTimeout(function(){ 
          window.clearInterval(myVar); 
      }, 500);             
  }
  function myTimer() {
      if ($('.goog-te-combo option:first').length) {
          $('.goog-te-combo option:first').html('Translate');
          cleartimer();
      }
  }
  var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 0); 
};


function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  var x = new google.translate.TranslateElement({
  pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'af,ach,ak,am,ar,az,be,bem,bg,bh,bn,br,bs,ca,chr,ckb,co,crs,cs,cy,da,de,ee,el,en,eo,es,es-419,et,eu,fa,fi, fo,fr,fy,ga,gaa,gd,gl,gn,gu,ha,haw,hi,hr,ht,hu,hy,ia, id,ig,is,it,iw,ja,jw,ka,kg,kk,km,kn,ko,kri,ku,ky,la, lg,ln,lo,loz,lt,lua,lv,mfe,mg,mi,mk,ml,mn,mo,mr,ms,mt, ne,nl,nn,no,nso,ny,nyn,oc,om,or,pa,pcm,pl,ps,pt-BR, pt-PT,qu,rm,rn,ro,ru,rw,sd,sh,si,sk,sl,sn,so,sq,sr, sr-ME,st,su,sv,sw,ta,te,tg,th,ti,tk,tl,tn,to,tr,tt, tum,tw,ug,uk,ur,uz,vi,wo,xh,yi,yo,zh-CN,zh-TW,zu',
  layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.VERTICAL
  }, 'google_translate_element');
  

  x.X.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    observer.observe(event.target.closest('html'), {
      attributes: true, 
      attributeFilter: ['class'],
      childList: false, 
      characterData: false
    })
    });
}


$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.goog-te-gadget').html($('.goog-te-gadget').children());
  $("#google-translate").fadeIn('1000');
    renameGoogleSelectDropdown();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="google-translate">
  <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#google-translate {
  display: none;
}
```

---

**Edit 8/5/21**

**This has broken again** :( And when I use console.log(x), I get `ReferenceError: x is not defined`.

How can I find the new classname in the Google widget Javascript? It's here: pastebin.com/xWVES3r1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here logging x you will find `querySelector` under an object `V`.
`x.V.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', (event) => {`

Fixed this issue on jsfiddle.
But this seems as generated classname so its susceptible to changes.
`document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', (event) => {`

works fine incase you are not using `select` anywhere else.
[image: Object V in fiddler]

Comment: That's interesting, thanks. So the class name is generated by the Google widget function, which we of course have no control over? And by select, you mean https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select ?

Comment: Yes since you are dependent on google widget and with each release they can change their classes.

Comment: Jerin, Thanks for your help last spring; it appears this has broken again :( And when I use console.log(x), I get `ReferenceError: x is not defined`. How can I find the new classname in the Google widget Javascript? it's here: https://pastebin.com/xWVES3r1

Comment: In your `https://jsfiddle.net/8m2xkez4/` I replaced with `x.U.querySelector('select')`. Since it's auto-generated would opt for some lopping of `x.CAPITAL_CHAR.querySelector` isn't undefined and the querySelector function exists.

Comment: Thanks, `U` works. But I'm not clear on why `U` works and how you decided it would work. Did Google change the variable in their widget?

Comment: Previously I did say how google might be obfuscating the code. So whenever they release a new version the `classnames` might change. Hence you could try instead using `document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change'`